# Calculated column with shift

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the base DataFrame:

```
 g_accessor  number_opened  number_closed
0     49 - 20            3.0            1.0
1     50 - 20            2.0           14.0
2     51 - 20            1.0            6.0
3     52 - 20            0.0            6.0
4      1 - 21            1.0            4.0
5      2 - 21            3.0            5.0
6      3 - 21            4.0           11.0
7      4 - 21            2.0            7.0
8      5 - 21            6.0           10.0
9      6 - 21            2.0            8.0
10     7 - 21            4.0            9.0
11     8 - 21            2.0            3.0
12     9 - 21            2.0            1.0
13    10 - 21            1.0           11.0
14    11 - 21            6.0            3.0
15    12 - 21            3.0            3.0
16    13 - 21            2.0            6.0
17    14 - 21            5.0            9.0
18    15 - 21            9.0           13.0
19    16 - 21            7.0            7.0
20    17 - 21            9.0            4.0
21    18 - 21            3.0            8.0
22    19 - 21            6.0            3.0
23    20 - 21            6.0            1.0
24    21 - 21            3.0            5.0
25    22 - 21            5.0            3.0
26    23 - 21            1.0            0.0
```

I want to add a calculated new column `number_active` which relies on previous values. For this I'm trying to use `pd.DataFrame.shift()`, like this:

```
# Creating new column and setting all rows to 0
df['number_active'] = 0
# Active from previous period
PREVIOUS_PERIOD_ACTIVE = 22
# Calculating active value for first period in the DataFrame, based on `PREVIOUS_PERIOD_ACTIVE`
df.iat[0,3] = (df.iat[0,1] + PREVIOUS_PERIOD_ACTIVE) - df.iat[0,2]
# Calculating all columns using DataFrame.shift()
df['number_active'] = (df['number_opened'] + df['number_active'].shift(1)) - df['number_closed']
# Recalculating first active value as it was overwritten in the previous step. 
df.iat[0,3] = (df.iat[0,1] + PREVIOUS_PERIOD_ACTIVE) - df.iat[0,2]
```

The result:

```
   g_accessor  number_opened  number_closed  number_active
0     49 - 20            3.0            1.0           24.0
1     50 - 20            2.0           14.0           12.0
2     51 - 20            1.0            6.0           -5.0
3     52 - 20            0.0            6.0           -6.0
4      1 - 21            1.0            4.0           -3.0
5      2 - 21            3.0            5.0           -2.0
6      3 - 21            4.0           11.0           -7.0
7      4 - 21            2.0            7.0           -5.0
8      5 - 21            6.0           10.0           -4.0
9      6 - 21            2.0            8.0           -6.0
10     7 - 21            4.0            9.0           -5.0
11     8 - 21            2.0            3.0           -1.0
12     9 - 21            2.0            1.0            1.0
13    10 - 21            1.0           11.0          -10.0
14    11 - 21            6.0            3.0            3.0
15    12 - 21            3.0            3.0            0.0
16    13 - 21            2.0            6.0           -4.0
17    14 - 21            5.0            9.0           -4.0
18    15 - 21            9.0           13.0           -4.0
19    16 - 21            7.0            7.0            0.0
20    17 - 21            9.0            4.0            5.0
21    18 - 21            3.0            8.0           -5.0
22    19 - 21            6.0            3.0            3.0
23    20 - 21            6.0            1.0            5.0
24    21 - 21            3.0            5.0           -2.0
25    22 - 21            5.0            3.0            2.0
26    23 - 21            1.0            0.0            1.0
```

Oddly, it seems that only the first active value (index 1) is calculated correctly (since the value at index 0 is calculated independently, via `df.iat`). For the rest of the values it seems that `number_closed` is interpreted as negative value - for some reason.

##### What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to be doing the calculations on cumulative sums of the opened and closed columns?

Comment: @pbarber No, I am aware of the `cumsum()` method. I basically need to do `opened + previous_active - closed`. For `previous_active` I need to use `shift(1)` - which seems logical. The result, however, seems not.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding here, but is the number of active tickets in any month not the difference between the cumulative sum of all tickets opened in the preceding months and the cumulative sum of all tickets closed in the preceding months? Apologies if I have missed the point of the question.

Comment: The question is rather why the `shift()` method is generating the odd result and what am I doing wrong. About your logic - it is partly right. active tickets are the difference between opened and closed plus the active from previous interval (in this case, the previous value). Basically active tickets are inherited throughout time, they are not isolated per period - in which case it would have been just `opened - closed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that the result for the previous row is available when the current row is calculated. This is not how pandas calculations work. Pandas calculations treat each row in isolation, unless you are applying multi-row operations like `cumsum` and `shift`.

I would calculate the number active with a minimal example as:

```py
df = pandas.DataFrame({'ignore': ['a','b','c','d','e'], 'number_opened': [3,4,5,4,3], 'number_closed':[1,2,2,1,2]})
df['number_active'] = df['number_opened'].cumsum() + 22 - df['number_closed'].cumsum()
```

This gives a result of:

|  | ignore | number_opened | number_closed | number_active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 3 | 1 | 24 |
| 1 | b | 4 | 2 | 26 |
| 2 | c | 5 | 2 | 29 |
| 3 | d | 4 | 1 | 32 |
| 4 | e | 3 | 2 | 33 |

The code in your question with my minimal example gave:

|  | ignore | number_opened | number_closed | number_active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 3 | 1 | 24 |
| 1 | b | 4 | 2 | 26 |
| 2 | c | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | d | 4 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | e | 3 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: I am aware. I do use `shift` as mentioned in the question. Moreover, the calculation is right, but only for the first row and index 1 (index0 is calculated manually and inserted via `iat`) - mentioned this as well. For the rest it changes to the negative of the value (which is what is odd and I don't understand) and continues. Thanks for trying, though your answer should have rather been a clarification comment.

Comment: I've added an example of how you could do the calculation with `cumsum`. The reason that the `shift()` approach doesn't work is that for later rows the sum of preceding open and closed cases is not taken into account. The code in the question is subtracting number of closed cases from number of open cases in the later rows, as `shift()` uses the original value of active cases column, not the recalculated value.

Comment: Fantastic! It seems I misunderstood your logic. Thanks a lot for the solution